# Unable to get strong-remote example to work

Tags: node.js, curl, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm trying the example: https://github.com/strongloop/strong-remoting/blob/master/example/simple.js

When I invoke the curl, I get: **curl: (52) Empty reply from server**

and the node program exits with:
sm@valley:~/Documents/Projects/test/loopback.io/remoting$ node simple.js

/home/sm/Documents/Projects/test/loopback.io/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:603
    return fn.apply(this, arguments);
              ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
    at Object. (/home/sm/Documents/Projects/test/loopback.io/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:603:15)
    at Object.immediate._onImmediate (timers.js:348:16)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)

Any idea what I'm missing ?

Comment: The examples are out of date... See https://github.com/strongloop/strong-remoting/pull/169

Comment: Looks like that PR was merged. @subukris Can you try the example code again and make sure it works? If so, maybe delete this question?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to also look at https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-remote.  It's an example of the LB remote connector, which uses strong-remoting.  Not sure if it fits your use case, but AFAIK it works.